# System.out.println() は何故 PrintStream.println() だとコンパイルエラーになるのでしょうか？

Tags: java

お世話になります。
Javaを勉強しようと思いHello,WorldからサンプルプログラムとAPI仕様（ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/ ）を見比べながら勉強しています。

お馴染みのHello Worldですが、

```
System.out.println("Hello, world.");
```

となっておりAPIにはoutはSystemクラスのフィールドであると書いてあります。

フィールドOutの項目には

```
public static final PrintStream out
```

とありSystemクラスの中でプリントストリーム型？のフィールドoutを定義しているように思えました。

更に関連項目からはメソッドPrintln()はPrintStreamクラスに属する事がわかりました。

そこで試しにHello WorldのコードをSystem.out.println()からPrintStream.println()に書き換えてみるとエラーになりました。

どうしてこのような事が発生するのでしょうか？

Comment: `println`はインスタンスメソッドですから`PrintStream`クラスのインスタンスが必要です。なので、エラーになります。インスタンスは`PrintStream`クラスのコンストラクタで作成します。

Comment: もしかしたら知りたいのは次のサイトに書かれているようなことでしょうか…？ [学校では教えてくれない System.out.println() - 郡山からHello World](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/ytetsuwo/20110816)

Comment: @yukinohaneさま、@BLUEPIXYさま、回答ありがとうございます。    public static final PrintStream out　とAPIリファレンスにありましたのでインスタンス無しで運用出来るかと思いました。 何故systemクラスで可能なのかはYukinohaneさまのリンクが参考になりそうです。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ちなみに、    java.io.PrintStream obj = new java.io.PrintStream("C:\\Users\\Username\\outfile.txt");
  obj.println("test"); とする事でファイル相手の書き出しは出来ましたがコンソール出力が出来ません。　どのようにすればコンソール出力用に初期化が可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: `PrintStream obj = new PrintStream(System.out);
 
  obj.println("test");`, System.outをそのまま使えばいいですけど。

Comment: ありがとうございます。それって結局再帰的にsystemクラスにあるpublic static final PrintStream outを利用している訳で、なんでsystemクラスではコンパイルエラーにならなくて自分でやるとエラーになるのか？と言う部分からするとちょっと違う気がします。

Comment: _public static final PrintStream out　とAPIリファレンスにありましたのでインスタンス無しで運用出来るかと思いました。_ これって`out` のことで`PrintStream`のことではありませんよね？